# SingleOrDefault returning null when entity exists

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have the following entity class

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace ApiForVivtrack3.Entities
{
    [Table("PropertyPair")]
    public partial class PropertyPair
    {
        [Key]
        public int PairID { get; set; }
        public int PropertyNameID { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public byte LinkType { get; set; }
        public int LinkID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<byte> BehaviourType { get; set; }
        public Nullable<byte> DataType { get; set; }
        public Nullable<byte> Source { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("PropertyNameID")]
        public virtual PropertyName PropertyName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And the following method to add or update

```
 internal static PropertyPair MakePair(ApiDbContext connect, string propertyName, string PropertyValue,
            JobLine job)
        {
            var propertyNameId = SiteCache.LookUpPropertyNameId(propertyName);
            var pair = connect.PropertyPairs.SingleOrDefault(x =>x.PropertyNameID == propertyNameId && x.LinkID == job.JobID);
            if (pair == null)
            {
                Log.Information($"Adding pair {propertyNameId}  for jobid {job.JobID}");
                pair = new PropertyPair
                {
                    PropertyNameID = propertyNameId,
                    LinkID = job.JobID,
                    LinkType = 1,
                    Value = PropertyValue,
                    Source = 3,
                    DataType = 0,
                    BehaviourType = 0
                };
                connect.PropertyPairs.Add(pair);
            }
            else
            {
                Log.Information($"Updating pair Id {pair.PairID} {pair.PropertyNameID} {pair.PropertyName}");
                pair.Value = PropertyValue;
            }

            connect.SaveChanges();
            return pair;
        }
```

My problem is that when the pair is already in the database MakePair tries to add it.

I am using 2.1.1 from Microsoft.AspNetCore.App SDK

Serlog reports

```
log: 0636997507330005125,   Adding pair 1116  for jobid 543405, 27-Jul-19 1:12:13 AM +10:00,    837 ms
log: 0636997507330002543,   SaveJob:Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'PropertyPair' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection, DbCommandMethod executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.Execute(DbContext _, ValueTuple`2 parameters)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.Execute(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalDatabase.SaveChanges(IReadOnlyList`1 entries)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(IReadOnlyList`1 entriesToSave)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges()
   at ApiForVivtrack3.Feature_Job_Management.JobDataWriteHelper.MakePair(ApiDbContext connect, String propertyName, String PropertyValue, JobLine job) in d:\a\1\s\ApiForVivtrack3\Feature_Job_Management\JobDataWriteHelper.cs:line 102
   at ApiForVivtrack3.Feature_Job_Management.JobDataWrite.AddLineChangesWhereNeeded(ApiDbContext connect, LineItemRequestObject line, Head head, List`1 oldLineItemModifyInfos, Int32 lastJobId) in d:\a\1\s\ApiForVivtrack3\Feature_Job_Management\JobDataWrite.cs:line 380
```

However I am not trying to set PairID, which is an the identity column. The question is not a duplcate question of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47357624/cannot-insert-explicit-value-for-identity-column-in-table-movies-when-identit)

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Movies' when IDENTITY\_INSERT is set to OFF."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47357624/cannot-insert-explicit-value-for-identity-column-in-table-movies-when-identit)

Comment: No, because I am not trying to set the identity.

Comment: Someone made a comment that has been deleted.... but it was the answer. The entity had already been added in the DbContext but not the database. @RobertBaron was that you?

Comment: Yes, it was me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because a pair might have been added in the DbContext before `SaveChanges()` is called, you have to check whether the pair is in the database, or in the local context as follows.

```
var pair = connect.PropertyPairs.SingleOrDefault(x =>x.PropertyNameID == propertyNameId && x.LinkID == job.JobID);
if (pair == null)
    pair = connect.PropertyPairs.Local.SingleOrDefault(x =>x.PropertyNameID == propertyNameId  && x.LinkID == job.JobID);
```